# Pyspark Create Model with Coefficient & Intercept

Tags: java, pyspark

I am wondering if it is possible to construct a model(linear regression / logistic regression only with coefficient & intercept) For scikit-learn, things worked smoothly -- I could just set those variables for the model and predict worked.
For pyspark, I am having more trouble. I couldn't set those variables in scala. Since model takes in java_model as parameters, I am trying to create a java_model with pyspark/py4j and use it to create a pyspark model.

Here is what I am trying to do as a test.

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SQLContext
from pyspark.mllib.linalg import DenseVector

sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
sql_ctx = SQLContext(sc)
vect =  DenseVector([1.0, 2.0])
test = sc._jvm.org.apache.spark.ml.regression.LinearRegressionModel(vect, 1.0)
```

but then I get this error

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute '_get_object_id'
```

Seems like vect has self.array which is ndarray, and py4j cannot convert it to java DenseVector. Has anyone tried a similar attempt?

Comment: I know it is possible to save / load, but I am wondering if there is any simpler way. -- simply with coefficients / intercepts.

Comment: have you found a way to save the coefficients/intercepts separate from model save/load., i can print it out on the screen..